# PHP To Run Bash Command

Tags: php, bash, twitter-bootstrap, lamp

I am attempting to make a simple php form that executes a bash script that creates keys on a remote server. I've looked around here and found a couple different options. I've been able to get some results using shell_exec() and passthu() but only for commands like ls and echo. The problem is it doesn't show me the output. I don't think its being executed. I am sure the bash script is working because I use it daily.

Ideally, I would like to enter a value that is passed through to the script and then displays the output.
[Form Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozBLQ.png)

FORM:

```
<form action="aws_create.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="aws_id" id="inputawsid" type="number" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="000000000000">
    </div>
    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

POST: aws_create.php

```
<?php
$awsid  = $_POST["aws_id"];
$output = passthru("/usr/local/bin/createkeys.sh $awsid");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: The output is just empty. It does not even show a shell error

Comment: also tried  "$output = exec('createkeys.sh '.escapeshellarg($awsid));"

Comment: what does `/usr/local/bin/createkeys.sh` this do ?

Comment: @ThiruShetty It uses AWS CLI Tool. It just creates a IAM ROLE. its maybe 3 different aws cli commands.

Comment: have you tried shell_exec?

Comment: @Wils Yes, that was one of the first attempts.

Comment: Did you try this way? $output = passthru("/usr/bin/sh -x /usr/local/bin/createkeys.sh $awsid");

Comment: @VigneshRamsubbose Same response. No response

Answer (score 0):

void passthru ( string $command [, int &$return_var ] )
http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

As you can see passthru returns void so in your line

```
$output = passthru("/usr/local/bin/createkeys.sh $awsid");
```

the variable $output will never have your output. You need to change it in to something like:

```
$output="";
passthru("/usr/local/bin/createkeys.sh $awsid", $output);
```

Add the command parameter you give is wrong, because you are giving createkeys.sh, the string "$awsid" as a parameter as opposed to the value of the variable $awsid. Same for

```
 echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

you are echoing a string.
Try changing your script to something like:

```
$awsid  = $_POST["aws_id"];
$output = "";
passthru("/usr/local/bin/createkeys.sh ".$awsid, $output);
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
```

Comment: Hi Daniel! It gave me an interesting output. The output was just the number 0. Nothing else. I was hoping to see the terminal output here.

Comment: Well that is something, at least you know that passthru does run createkeys.sh because it changes $output from empty string to 0, but you won't see terminal output(I'm not sure what you mean by that), you should see what createkeys.sh outputs.